# DOMNodeList, xPath and PHP

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath, screen-scraping

I am parsing an HTML page with DOM and XPath in PHP.

I have to fetch a nested `<Table...></table>` from the HTML.

I have defined a query using FirePath in the browser which is pointing to

```
html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table
```

When I run the code it says `DOMNodeList` is fetched having length 0. My objective is to spout out the queried `<Table>` as a string. This is an HTML scraping script in PHP.

Below is the function. Please help me how can I extract the required `<table>`

```
$pageUrl = "http://www.boc.cn/sourcedb/whpj/enindex.html";

getExchangeRateTable($pageUrl);


function getExchangeRateTable($url){
    $htmlTable = "";
    $xPathTable = nulll;
    $xPathQuery1 = "html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table";

    if(strlen($url)==0){die('Argument exception: method call [getExchangeRateTable] expects a string of URL!');}

    // initialize objects
    $page = tidyit($url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($page);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    // $elements is sppearing as DOMNodeList
    $elements = $xpath->query($xPathQuery1);

    // print_r($elements);
    foreach($elements as $e){
        $e->firstChild->nodeValue;  
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but I think what you want is `table[position()=2]`  instead of `table[2]` and such.  I'm not entirely confident, which is why this is not an answer.

Comment: There is a number of packages to get Forex rates. You dont need to scrape them.

Comment: @Levi - `table[position()=2]` and `table[2]` are equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the tbody's from your XPath query - they are in most cases inserted by your browser, as is with the page you are trying to scrape.

```
/html/body/table[2]/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tr/td/table
```

This will most likely work.

However, its probaly more safe to use a different XPath. Following XPath will select the first th based on it's textual content, then select the tr's parent - a tbody or table:

```
//th[contains(text(),'Currency Name')]/parent::tr/parent::*
```

Comment: More straightforward version of your second expression (without backtracking): `//*[tr/th[contains(.,'Currency Name')]]`

Comment: fictitious tbody was the issue. FirFox.

Answer (score 3):

have you try like this

```
$dom = new domDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($tes); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName("table");
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("tr"); 
print_r($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath query should be with a leading `/` like :-

```
/html/...
```